# Open and read all text Files in your directory and filter them using regular expression, python

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk

So, I was given a use case. The use case is to find PHI in multiple text files using regular expressions and python at once.

So basically, Open all text files in your directory and then filter the content of each file with regular expressions to see which file has PHI in them.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need regular expressions for that. Use `os.listdir` to get all the files in the directory you need. Open them with the `open` method, read the contents and filter the ones you need using `if "PHI" in contents:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is using `glob` rather than `listdir`, but this might be a possible method. No regular expressions involved here either though.

```
import glob

folder_path = "C:\Temp"
file_pattern = "\*.txt"
search_string = "hello"

match_list = []

folder_contents = glob.glob(folder_path + file_pattern)

for file in folder_contents:
    print("Checking", file)
    read_file = open(file, 'rt').read()

    if search_string in read_file:
        match_list.append(file)

print("Files containing search string")
for file in match_list:
    print(file)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That works well. Do you know how to add a regular expression filter in there? For example if i wanted to search for this regex,r'\d\d\d[-]\d\d\d[-]\d\d\d\d', how would I implement that?